# Custom query regex MongoDB + Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to write a "startsWith" query in Spring Data, using MongoDB. If I write this in Mongo shell, it works, lists every e-mail address starting with letter x or X (case insensitive): `db.user.find({email:/^x/i})`

However, this doesn't:

```
@Query(value = "{'$or':[{'name':?0},{'email':?0}]}")
List<User> findAllByFreeTextSearch(String keyword);
```

I tried to add the /^.../i to the keyword itself, and in a dozen combinations to the @Query but without luck. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: because when you send a String to your query it will be translate it like so `{'$or':[{'name':'/^x/'},{'email':'/^x/'}]}`, note the quotes, and this cause a problem

Comment: @YCF_L I've also tried something like /^?0/ without luck. Can you please show a working example?

Comment: even this will be translated with the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/expression/ is alternative syntax used in shell & js drivers.

You need to pass "^x" as keyword for java driver.

Try

```
@Query(value = "{$or:[{name:{$regex:?0,$options:'i'}},{email:{$regex:?0,$options:'i'}}]}")
List<User> findAllByFreeTextSearch(String keyword);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the / sign's purpose. I'll award you the bounty as soon as the system allows!

Comment: How is this still a regular expression search?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky My main point was to pass the regular expression as string without the / syntax but you are correct. I copied paste the query in the question. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data wraps those parameters by intent to prevent malicious patterns from being executed via an annotated query.

Please use `$regex` like below for that.

```
@Query("{'$or':[{ 'name' : { '$regex' : '?0', '$options' : 'i'}}, ...")
List<User> findAllByFreeTextSearch(String keyword);
```

Comment: The keyword variable should be concatenated like "/^" + keyword + "/"? Because it's not working. :/

Comment: You don't want to use slashes - they are special syntax to designate regular expression.  If you have regular expression as a *string* then you should use `{"$regex":"^x", "$options":"i"}` syntax.